# Синхронный запрос к серверу

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Возможно ли, если да, то как, сделать синхронный запрос к серверу (не java) стандартными способами?

Answer (score 2):

По идее, синхронный запрос к серверу не имеет смысла и всегда можно без него обойтись. Кроме того, выполнение синхронных сетевых операций вредно при использовании их из основной очереди событий в любых UI-приложениях. По этой причине всегда по возможности следует использовать именно асинхронные запросы. Видимо, по этим причинам в GWT нельзя ничего такого делать синхронно.

Но если **НУ ОЧЕНЬ ХОЧЕТСЯ** сделать плохо, то можете сделать "нативный" метод и реализовать его через XMLHttpRequest, настроив его соответствующим образом.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m да ты мега крут

Comment: @evm Не знаю, что и думать... Я в недоумении. :O